# correct update of state array in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i tried to build a TODO app with React Native

```
const [ enteredGoal, setEnteredGoal ] = useState("");
const [ courseGoals, setCourseGoals ] = useState([]);

const goalInputHandler = (enteredText) => {
  setEnteredGoal(enteredText);
};


const addGoalHandler = () => {
  let arrGoals = courseGoals;
  arrGoals.push(enteredGoal);
  setCourseGoals(arrGoals);
};

return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>
      <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
        <TextInput style={styles.input} onChangeText={goalInputHandler}/>
        <Button title="ADD" onPress={addGoalHandler}/>
      </View>
      <View>
        { 
          courseGoals.map((goal) => {
            <View key={goal} style={styles.listItem}><Text>{goal}</Text></View>
          })
        }
      </View>
    </View>
  );
```

the idea is to list the setCourseGoals array, but apparently after assigning a new text, it doesn't list anything. Its not until the text changes that the list is re-rendered. Any idea on why this happens?? the "useState" function is asynchronous, which assigns the value after rendering? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is coming from `addGoalHandler`

```js
const addGoalHandler = () => {
  let arrGoals = courseGoals;
  arrGoals.push(enteredGoal);
  setCourseGoals(arrGoals);
};
```

What happened was you are using `push` method to push it to `courseGoals` which was mutated the state, one of the option you can do is update to below

```js
const addGoalHandler = () => {
  let arrGoals = [...courseGoals, enteredGoal];
  setCourseGoals(arrGoals);
};
```

The idea is that, using spread syntax allowing you to create a new copy of array instead of mutated the previous state, and of course it can be shorten down to single line as below

```js
const addGoalHandler = () => setCourseGoals([...courseGoals,enteredGoal])
```

Comment: I understand that I should not mutate the states of my component, but I am using the push method on an independent variable to save the new "task", and then I am overwriting the data of courseGoals with a new array (like the example you give). for example if I use .concat instead of the push method, it works too. the problem seems to be the .push method. Does React prohibit mutations in any created variable?

Comment: I think I got it. the problem is that I am doing .push to a variable that refers to my state, and react does not allow state mutation. but if I do this:
`let arrGoals = [... courseGoals];`
`arrGoals.push (enteredGoal);`
There is no reference to my state, and I only extract its values, the problem is the reference, right? I am right?

Comment: @Raphael: Yes you are right, because `array` and `object` in `JavaScript` are shared by reference